# How To Print 3 Stacks On Screen In 3 Columns Of 7 In The Most Efficient Manner Java

Tags: java, stack

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to print three stacks to the screen in 3 columns of 7. It's basically like a card game.

So far my method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Prints the cards to the screen.
 */
private void printTrick() {


    for (int i = 0; i < bigStack.size(); i++){
        leftStack.push(bigStack.pop());     
        middleStack.push(bigStack.pop());    
        rightStack.push(bigStack.pop());   
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        System.out.print(leftStack.elementAt(j) + "\t");
        System.out.print(middleStack.elementAt(j) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rightStack.elementAt(j) + "\t");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

All I want to do is print the numbers on the screen in 3 columns of 7. There is one way I can write it that does work which looks like:

```
/**
 * Prints the cards to the screen.
 */
private void printTrick() {


    int i=0;

    while(i<21)
    {
        left.push(bigStack.pop());
        i++;
        middle.push(bigStack.pop());
        i++;
        right.push(bigStack.pop());
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        System.out.print(leftStack.elementAt(j) + "\t");
        System.out.print(middleStack.elementAt(j) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rightStack.elementAt(j) + "\t");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But it looks inefficient with the three increments inside the while loop. So I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to make this work. And also if it is possible to have the three stacks printed to the screen using **one** System.out.println() method rather than the three that I have, because when I tried to use the + operator like this:

System.out.println(leftStack.elementAt(j) + middleStack.elementAt(j) + rightStack.elementAt(j));

I got a **'bad operand types for binary operator '+' first type: Card second type: Card'** error. I just presumed the:

first type:Card second type Card

meant I was trying to System.out.print(object + object + object); which now I've just learned I can't do.

And also if there is a better way to print out the numbers in columns rather than the (" \t "); I'm using.

Sorry if this seems trivial I'm not a very strong programmer yet any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: IMO System.out.println(leftStack.elementAt(j) + "" + middleStack.elementAt(j) + "" + rightStack.elementAt(j)) is OK

Comment: Cheers robocoder that seemed to work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
for (int i = 0; i < bigStack.size(); i++){
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < bigStack.size()/3; i++){
```

Comment: Hi Boris, I change that line but I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException saying 4 > = 4 error in the second for loop now. my bigStack size is initialised to 21 if that's any help :)

Comment: What's the second loop? There are two methods with four loops inside :)